iOS: .ipa file generated via GitHub Actions lacks 'aps-environment' entitlement for push notifications
I am currently working on an iOS application that utilizes push notifications. We have configured push notifications entitlement (aps-environment) in Xcode and it works correctly when generating build manually.
However, when the .ipa file is generated through our GitHub Actions pipeline, the entitlement seems to be missing.
I am using the same profiles/certs for build generation in both.
